# How to set CTreeCtrl's item height with different value?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

My need my tree control to have different items' height? How can I do it?
I try to handle MEASUREITEM but it doesnt work. CTreeCtrl::SetItemHeight() changes item height but for all items.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question... To be honest, I don't think it's possible. At least not without doing the drawing of the tree yourself (which you probably don't want to do as it's a lot of work).

Comment: There is a solution for this, but I don't think it is utter solution. I used a customized CListBox (which I can change height of every items variously). In this new control, I use a tree-data structure (here is a good one: http://tree.phi-sci.com/). There is much less work than drawing complete tree. It works for my needs, but i'm still looking for better solution.